# Node.js MEAN Stack App working locally, but can't deploy to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment, mean-stack

My MEAN App is organized:

```
MyApp
  >client
    >app
    >node_modules
    >public
    >views
    >bower.json
    >Gruntfile.js
    >package.json
  >server
    >config
    >models
    >node_modules
    >routes
    >app.js
    >package.json
```

Everything works well serving app.js locally. However, I haven't been able to successfully deploy to Heroku. I have some confusion regarding package.json and suspect this may be at the root of my problem. I have two package.json files... one in client that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "******",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "******",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

And, one package.json in >server:

```
{
  "name": "**********",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "*********",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "*******",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.5",
    "ejs": "^2.3.3",
    "express": "^4.13.1",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "mongoose": "^4.1.0",
    "mongoskin": "^1.3.20",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I've initialized the heroku git in the MyApp folder and pushed. The build succeeds, but opening the App does not work. The logs throw many npm ERR!s

I tried writing a new package.json in the MyApp folder without success. I'm not sure if that's necessary:

```
{
  "name": "*******",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "*********",
  "main": "server/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "********",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

logs:

```
± |master ✓| → git push heroku master
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.46 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.11.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.8.6
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        └── (empty)
remote:        
remote:  !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 18.4M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v13
remote:        https://*********.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/*********.git
   *********  master -> master

 2016-07-30 23:31:51 ☆  *********-iMac in /Volumes/*********/Developer/*********
± |master ✓| → heroku logs
2016-07-31T05:25:47.224161+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-07-31T05:25:47.224484+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server/app.js
2016-07-31T05:25:47.224317+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-07-31T05:25:47.224644+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-07-31T05:25:47.224804+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs *********
2016-07-31T05:25:47.225116+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls *********
2016-07-31T05:25:47.225273+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-07-31T05:25:47.224960+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-07-31T05:25:47.228732+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T05:25:47.228987+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-07-31T05:25:47.229127+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-07-31T05:25:47.327229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-31T05:25:47.366898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-31T05:41:46.439742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=*********.herokuapp.com request_id=91de90e2-0bf5-4863-b783-ceecaa8fde8d fwd="172.112.229.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-31T05:48:30.859479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-31T05:48:32.839176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-07-31T05:48:35.391181+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T05:48:35.391203+00:00 app[web.1]: > *********@1.0.0 start /app
2016-07-31T05:48:35.391204+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/app.js
2016-07-31T05:48:35.391204+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959374+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959393+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959395+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959395+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959397+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './config/config'
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959398+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959398+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959399+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959399+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959400+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/app.js:6:23)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959400+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959401+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959401+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959402+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959402+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959403+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:148:18)
2016-07-31T05:48:35.959409+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:405:3
2016-07-31T05:48:35.969614+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T05:48:35.977274+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
2016-07-31T05:48:35.977679+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-07-31T05:48:35.978481+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-07-31T05:48:35.977929+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-07-31T05:48:35.979067+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-07-31T05:48:35.979324+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! *********@1.0.0 start: `node server/app.js`
2016-07-31T05:48:35.979509+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-07-31T05:48:35.979695+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-07-31T05:48:35.979864+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the *********@1.0.0 start script 'node server/app.js'.
2016-07-31T05:48:35.980260+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ********* package,
2016-07-31T05:48:35.980075+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-07-31T05:48:35.980433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-07-31T05:48:35.980617+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-07-31T05:48:35.980796+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server/app.js
2016-07-31T05:48:35.980959+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-07-31T05:48:35.981118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs *********
2016-07-31T05:48:35.981270+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-07-31T05:48:35.981425+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls *********
2016-07-31T05:48:35.981595+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-07-31T05:48:35.985488+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T05:48:35.985775+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-07-31T05:48:35.985852+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-07-31T05:48:36.069623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-31T05:48:36.098125+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-31T06:14:31.189397+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-31T06:30:06.982191+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-31T06:31:50.317210+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 06516f1 by *********@gmail.com
2016-07-31T06:31:50.317272+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v13 created by *********@gmail.com
2016-07-31T06:31:50.511812+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-31T06:31:50.511822+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-07-31T06:31:50.692916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-31T06:31:52.514294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-07-31T06:31:54.849264+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
2016-07-31T06:31:54.850042+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-07-31T06:31:54.849823+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-07-31T06:31:54.850399+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-07-31T06:31:54.851691+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T06:31:54.852581+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-07-31T06:31:54.852716+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-07-31T06:31:54.852805+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-07-31T06:31:54.852909+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-07-31T06:31:54.860771+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T06:31:54.860966+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-07-31T06:31:54.861099+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-07-31T06:31:54.917805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-31T06:31:54.918636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-31T06:31:54.941001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-31T06:31:56.382143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-07-31T06:31:58.484779+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
2016-07-31T06:31:58.485394+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-07-31T06:31:58.485718+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-07-31T06:31:58.486234+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-07-31T06:31:58.488049+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T06:31:58.489425+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-07-31T06:31:58.489756+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-07-31T06:31:58.489606+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-07-31T06:31:58.498880+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T06:31:58.489907+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-07-31T06:31:58.499107+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-07-31T06:31:58.499260+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-07-31T06:31:58.598275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-31T06:31:58.605133+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-31T06:32:40.380168+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=*********.herokuapp.com request_id=********* fwd="*********" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I've resolved the .config problem, but the app is still not working on heroku. I've added "start" to my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "**********",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "*********",
  "main": "server/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server/app.js"
  },
  "author": "********",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I've tried "start" with both "node server/app.js" and simply "node app.js."

The logs now:

```
2016-07-31T20:30:57.827511+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-31T20:30:57.827516+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-07-31T20:30:57.825021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-31T20:30:59.273318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-07-31T20:31:01.202950+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:31:01.202968+00:00 app[web.1]: > *********@1.0.0 start /app
2016-07-31T20:31:01.202969+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2016-07-31T20:31:01.202970+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256865+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256867+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256867+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256868+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256869+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256869+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256870+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256871+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:148:18)
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256870+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2016-07-31T20:31:01.256871+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:405:3
2016-07-31T20:31:01.262989+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:31:01.269797+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
2016-07-31T20:31:01.270174+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-07-31T20:31:01.270404+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-07-31T20:31:01.270985+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-07-31T20:31:01.271447+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-07-31T20:31:01.271618+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! *********@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2016-07-31T20:31:01.271772+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-07-31T20:31:01.271940+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-07-31T20:31:01.272096+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the *********@1.0.0 start script 'node app.js'.
2016-07-31T20:31:01.272260+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-07-31T20:31:01.272573+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-07-31T20:31:01.272417+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ********* package,
2016-07-31T20:31:01.272723+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-07-31T20:31:01.272885+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node app.js
2016-07-31T20:31:01.273189+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs *********
2016-07-31T20:31:01.273037+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-07-31T20:31:01.273340+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-07-31T20:31:01.273493+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls *********
2016-07-31T20:31:01.277062+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:31:01.277274+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-07-31T20:31:01.273651+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-07-31T20:31:01.277415+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-07-31T20:31:01.346939+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-31T20:31:01.331495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-31T20:31:12.076774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=*********.herokuapp.com request_id=2a1195*********ece8bb2c fwd="172.1*********71" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-31T20:34:47.098473+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 388b5ab by *********@gmail.com
2016-07-31T20:34:47.098521+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v16 created by *********@gmail.com
2016-07-31T20:34:47.266271+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-31T20:34:47.266277+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-07-31T20:34:47.319491+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-31T20:34:48.929096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-07-31T20:34:50.867157+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:34:50.867172+00:00 app[web.1]: > *********@1.0.0 start /app
2016-07-31T20:34:50.867172+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/app.js
2016-07-31T20:34:50.867173+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278936+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/server/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278950+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw e
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278951+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278953+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/server/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278952+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278953+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278955+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278957+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278954+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:440:18)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278956+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278957+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278959+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278958+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bindings (/app/server/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278958+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278959+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278960+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278961+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278963+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278961+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278962+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.278963+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/models/user.js:3:23)
2016-07-31T20:34:51.294193+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-07-31T20:34:51.286768+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:34:51.294540+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-07-31T20:34:51.293678+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
2016-07-31T20:34:51.293977+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-07-31T20:34:51.295092+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! *********@1.0.0 start: `node server/app.js`
2016-07-31T20:34:51.294922+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-07-31T20:34:51.295255+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-07-31T20:34:51.295593+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the *********@1.0.0 start script 'node server/app.js'.
2016-07-31T20:34:51.295436+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-07-31T20:34:51.295738+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-07-31T20:34:51.295847+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ********* package,
2016-07-31T20:34:51.296198+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server/app.js
2016-07-31T20:34:51.296081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-07-31T20:34:51.295954+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-07-31T20:34:51.296412+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs *********
2016-07-31T20:34:51.296304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-07-31T20:34:51.296517+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-07-31T20:34:51.296625+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls *********
2016-07-31T20:34:51.296730+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-07-31T20:34:51.300465+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-31T20:34:51.300731+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-07-31T20:34:51.300635+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-07-31T20:34:51.385297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-31T20:34:51.373820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-31T20:35:00.298699+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=*********.herokuapp.com request_id=a09912*********-f3aee9e3a05a fwd="*********" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Running "npm start" locally works if my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "*********",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "*********",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cd server && node app.js"
  },
  "author": "*********",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This still doesn't work when deployed, however.

Comment: Need to see the ERRs you mention - not enough info

Comment: Are you using TypeScript and are your transpiled JS files being deployed?

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 errors :

**First**,

Not a problem with npm, but with your code :

```
Error: Cannot find module './config/config'
```

So I guess in your app.js you do a `require('./config/config')` that is not present (.gitignore ?)

**Second**,

`npm ERR! missing script: start`

you should specify a start action in you package :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
```

Comment: .config/config fixed, thank you. I've attempted to incorporate "start" into my package.json, without success. Details and new logs added to original post.

Comment: Is there some conflict between "main" and "start" in package.json? I just need to initialize server/app.js